# How to sync email sent from Mail to Yahoo Business Mail server?

Tags: macos, mail.app

When I send email through Mail app using my Yahoo Business mail account the sent mail is only stored locally and not on the server. How do I make the sent mail stored on the server as well?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I had to set the INBOX to use the IMAP servers and then highlight IMAP server's Sent box, hit "Mailbox" in the top menu bar, highlight "Use this Mailbox For" and choose Sent.